# MySQL query - sort by doing a count in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a standard query like

```
SELECT * FROM events
```

And I have another table called clicks with this data

eventid
clicks

I want the query to add all the clicks together for each eventid, and then sort the events by clicks. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select e.eventid,IFNULL(SUM(c.clicks),0) as TotalClicks
from events e LEFT JOIN
     clicks c on e.eventid=c.eventid
group by e.eventid
order by SUM(c.clicks)
```

Comment: it seems events and clicks are not part of the events table

Comment: This worked for me! Just one little problem: it only shows the events that actually has any clicks registered. Some events will have 0 clicks in the clicks-table (and therefore not have a row in the clicks-table). Is it possible to show them aswell, but just with 0 clicks?

Comment: Perfect! Amazing how fast you response!

Comment: If I want to add some WHERE-conditions related to the events - where in the query would I insert these?

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard: `Where` should be right before `group by`

Comment: Thanks you! It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery and join:

```
SELECT * FROM events join (select eventid, sum(clicks) as clicks from clicks group by eventid) as c
order by c.clicks
```